# CodeIgniter - How to return values from an ajax method?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to pass a date into an ajax function and get the relevant type and title according to that date separately from the database.

I have used the following **Model** function.

```
function get_reservation_for_add_popup($date_cal) {
        $this->db->select('reservations.title,reservations.type');
        $this->db->from('reservations');
        $this->db->where('reservations.date_cal', $date_cal);
        $this->db->where('reservations.is_deleted', '0');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();      
    }
```

My **Controller** function is like following

```
function get_title_and_type() {
        $reservation_service = new Reservation_service();        
        $data['reservation_pop_up'] = $reservation_service->get_reservation_for_add_popup($this->input->post('date', TRUE));    

        echo $data;
    }
```

In the **View** I want to get title and the type separately for the particular day. I used the following ajax function. But i don't know how to return values from an ajax function and how to catch them into variables.

```
var date = $('#date').val();
                var title=[];
                var type=[];

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/dashboard/get_title_and_type',
                    data: 'date=' + date,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        return msg;                        
                    }
                });
```

Since i am very new to ajax it will be a great help if someone give me an idea.

Comment: ajax is ASYNC so you don't return values from an ajax function, you write your program in the callback function. Write `console.log(msg)` instead of `return msg` and you would see the data you queried from database

Comment: See my answer ... and use GET method instead of POST

Comment: Actually your question is misleading title please elaborate what you need and what's not working over here

Comment: I mentioned the header directive in a comment in one of the answers and the use of the shorthand `$.post()`... Renders the use of `$.parseJSON(msg)` useless when done correctly... ;)

Answer (score 3):

In ajax Change following

```
data: 'date=' + date,
```

TO

```
data: {'date' : date},
```

Comment: @Sadikhasan this won't make any difference

Comment: @Uchiha If you don't then it give syntactically error.

Comment: @Sadikhasan now that you have edited your answer I look like an idiot. Previously it was `data: 'date' : date`

Nevermind, as long it helps the OP

Comment: @SudhirMishra You can point out my mistake but you ask to me `how would this work ?`

Answer (score 1):

In controller

```
function get_title_and_type() {
        $reservation_service = new Reservation_service();        
        $data['reservation_pop_up'] = $reservation_service->get_reservation_for_add_popup($this->input->post('date', TRUE));    

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

In your ajax add dataType json

```
var date = $('#date').val();
                var title=[];
                var type=[];

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/dashboard/get_title_and_type',
                    data: {'date' : date},
                    success: function(msg) {
                        return msg;                        
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I would add `header('Content-type: application/json');` to the controller action to force detection of JSON data being sent... Since jquery will detect that header, it will try to create a JSON object as response result in your success callback. I would also encourage the use of the shorthand `$.post(url, { ... data ...}, callback(jsonResponse) { ... code ... });`

Comment: Yes that's also fine.

Answer (score 1):

Send any kind of data JSON encoded from your PHP file

```
function get_title_and_type() {

        ..... your code here
        $data['test_msg_2'] = "Hello 1";
        $data['test_msg_2'] = "Hello 2";
        echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And in your JS

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/dashboard/get_title_and_type',
     data: 'date=' + date,
     success: function(msg) {
         msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
         console.log(msg.reservation_pop_up);   
         console.log(msg.test_msg_2);                      
         console.log(msg.test_msg_2);                   
     }
```